# iOS: How to get device system language from terminal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bash

I am trying to retrieve the current system language of the device connected to my MacBook from command line.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to get this information without reverse-engineering the protocol used to communicate with devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
ideviceinfo -q com.apple.international -k Language
```

Try [ideviceinfo](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice).

Answer (score -1):

you can system language by this

```
let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```